# jQuery add class to object with .get() method

Tags: jquery, html, dom, get, indexing

running into a weird thing and I'm not sure what's going on.

I've grabbed the index of a DOM element via `.index()`, found a matching element via `.get()` and I'm trying to add a class to it via `.addClass()`.

My console is returning the error: "`Uncaught TypeError: Object #<HTMLLIElement> has no method 'addClass'`"... which is especially odd because my Log shows the HTML element just fine (http://cloud.dhut.ch/image/2W3S0R3k2h2U)

Am I missing something? It's not returning in an array or anything. Confused.

Thanks!

JavaScript:

`nFLi.get(active).addClass('active')`;

Comment: Post more/relevant code here.

Comment: I am curious, what does `active` hold??

Answer (score 13, accepted):

You need to wrap it into a jquery object.

```
$(nFLi.get(active)).addClass('active');
```

Or you could use [.eq](http://api.jquery.com/eq/) method instead of `.get`, which returns a jquery object instead of original HTMLElement.

```
nFLi.eq(active).addClass('active');
```

Comment: +1, I thought I've answered first but unfortunately my internet connection sucks so i see you answered `14` minutes ago and I didn't get even a notification, lol...